# Is there a way of doing a 3-D matrix convolution in Fortran?

Tags: 3d, fortran, fft, convolution

I am not so familiar with Fortran, therefore i was wondering if it is possible to convolute two 3-D matrices, either through FFT or direct computation. If it is possible how would one do such a thing in Fortran?

Comment: I'm assuming by "3D matrices" you mean grids of points. Fortran doesn't support FFTs within the standard language, but there are many, many libraries that supply the functionality. FFTW ( https://www.fftw.org/ ) is probably the best known and most widely used.

Comment: Yes i mean a grid of points with 3D matrices. So this FFTW is a library that i have to call upon in Fortran to perform the FFT?

Comment: Do you also maybe have a reference to implementation of FFTW ?

Comment: Yes. The reference is the link in my first comment